# How to download edited table from selected tab in Shiny?

Tags: download, tabs, shiny, tabpanel, rhandsontable

I have created a Shiny app which takes .csv file as input and generates tabs based on the Grade column.

The data looks like this

```
Name    Age Score Grade
Jane    13  89    A
Hanna   14  67    B
Jack    13  80    A
Leena   14  78    B
Amy     12  65    B
Nina    14  90    A
Steven  12  45    C
Omy     13  59    C
```

The code will generate tables in each tab containing only rows of the dataset that match the Grade.
These tables are editable. I am trying to download the edited table from the active tabPanel, but I am stuck on what should be the content in the downloadHandler. I have attached my code for reference. Sorry for the messy code, I am fairly new to shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(  
    titlePanel("Scores"),  
    sidebarLayout(    
        sidebarPanel(      
            fileInput("file", "Upload the file"),      
            br(),     
            downloadButton('downloadData', 'Save as excel')   
        ),    
        mainPanel(uiOutput("op"))  
      )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({  
        file1 <- input$file   
        if (is.null(file1)) {
                  return()   
        }
          read.csv(file = file1$datapath) 
    })  

    fun1 <- function(x) {
            mydf <- data()
            DF <- mydf[(mydf$Grade == x), c(1:3)]
            table <- renderRHandsontable({
                  newtable<- rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL)
            })
           tabPanel(x, table)
    }

    output$op <- renderUI({
            if (is.null(data()))
                 helpText("File not uploaded!")
            else{
                mydf <- data()
                Tabs <- lapply((unique(mydf$Grade)), fun1)
                do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id = "tabs", Tabs))
        }
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
       filename = function() {
          'Edited table.xls'
       },
        # what should go in place of table
       content = function(file) {
           write.xlsx(table, file)
        }
     )  
   }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: use `hot_to_r` function as in this example https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/blob/0a08b185f5da8bd850626650258c62fadd93aca4/inst/examples/rhandsontable_output/server.R

Comment: Tried it. It gives error- second argument must be a list

Comment: To use `hot_to_r`, I think you need to have **named** `rhandsontableOutput` so you can refer to it. Right now your table id is dynamically generated and you cannot reference it. I suggest use renderUI to create named `rhandsontableOutput` first, then render the tables to them, then you can refer to each of them depending on your tab selection.

Comment: When I try and execute your code, I get an error: `ERROR: zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length`

I could download the edited data, I only tried CSV though using `DT` package using the builtin dataframes such as iris as shown in this example https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/28#issuecomment-236293247 but could not load the data, edit it and then download.